# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1912 (note 1 of 2)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1912 in my Great Grandfathers Civil Guard records there are two entries.

Here is the first one (split into two images):

[image]

[image]

This is the transcribed text so far:

> Ha abriendo solicitad al Juzgado de Instrucción de Jefe pa del E. S.
> (Excmo. Señor) xxx de la 2ª Región que el individuo contenido en este
> cueparerea (?) ante el como acusado en sumario por detención
> arbitraria del alcalde de Herrera y alentach contra el mismo, dicha.
> Superior anonadad he tenido a bien disformes con fecha 1 de Marzo ano
> marginal de acuerdo en xxx todo con xxx anditor General, que la
> Causa que por el Cuerpo se he informe seo inhibida a aquella
> jurisdicción, y que este individuo conformara antes el referindo
> juzgado y quede a xxx dis xxx como procesado por los delitos que se he
> causan.
>
> El 2º Jefe

I know this has something to do with a Judge!

---

##### Marginal

I notice the use of the term **marginal** again and it now makes more sense to me. In the left **margin** is the handwritten year (eg. 1913).

---

#### Translation

Translation so far based on the answer provided:

> The Court of Instruction (Examining Magistrate’s Court) of Estepa having requested from the E. S.
> (Excellency) C.Gral (Captain General) of the 2nd Region that the
> individual contained in this document appear before it *as a defendant
> in a summary for the arbitrary detention of the Mayor of Herrera and
> an attack on him*. Said Superior Authority has seen fit to order on the
> 7th of March of the marginal year, in agreement in xxx all with its
> Auditor General, that the Cause which has been instructed by the Corps
> be inhibited to that jurisdiction, and that this individual appear
> before the aforementioned court and be placed at its disposal as a
> defendant for the offences of which he is accused.
>
> The 2nd Chief

---

#### Update 1

According this this [page](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/spanish-english/juzgado-de-instrucci%C3%B3n) the phrase **Court of Instruction** should be **Examining Magistrate’s Court**.

---

#### Update 2

The same translation website has decided to translate **and an attack on him** as **and an attempt on his life**.

That is a rather drastic difference. In the answer it uses the word **assault**. Which phrase do you think it is best I go with, given the original text?

---

### Related Questions

- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1912 (note 2 of 2)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39454/28260)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestions

> **Habiendo solicitado el** Juzgado de Instrucción de **[Estepa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estepa_(Sevilla))** del E. S.
> (Excmo. Señor) **C.Gral (Capitán General)** de la 2ª Región que el individuo contenido en este
> **documento comparezca** ante **él** como acusado en sumario por detención
> arbitraria del alcalde de Herrera y **atentado** contra el mismo;  **dicha**
> Superior **autoridad ha** tenido a bien **disponer** con fecha **7** de Marzo año
> marginal de acuerdo en xxx todo con **su Auditor General**, que la Causa
> que por el Cuerpo se **ha instruido sea** inhibida a aquella jurisdicción, y
> que este individuo **comparezca ante** el **referido** juzgado y quede a **su disposición** como procesado por los delitos que se **le acusan**.
>
> El 2º Jefe

The remaining xxx is completely ilegible but you can supress it without affecting the meaning of the text.

Well, it seems that your ancestor had got some serious troubles with the mayor of Herrera in 1912. Illegal detention and assault, no less.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Wow. It is kind of amazing that this happened given the nature of the notes so far. We'll see what the second note for 1913 says about this, if anything. Originally I had the idea of writing to the Herrera Civil Guard address just to say my Great Grandfather had worked for them for a number of years. But if he had this cloud over his head ...hhmm. Maybe they would have knowledge of the circumstances.

Comment: I added a query to the question about **attack**, **attempt on life** and **assault**.