# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1912 (note 2 of 2)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1912 in my Great Grandfathers Civil Guard records there are two entries.

Here is the second one (start 1913 later - has 3 notes):

[image]

I thought that this note might have a baring on the first note (the Judicial stuff).

Transcribed text so far:

> El dia 11 de Agosto año marginal, se incogono al puerto de [Corcoya](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corcoya)
> para puesta el servicio de el clase, al que fue destinado por orden
> del Señor primer (1ª) Jefe de la Comandancia donde finio el ano.
>
> El 2º Jefe

I don't know if my efforts are accurate? I don't see any references to judges here but I do note he has now moved from **Herrera** to **Corcoya**. Might be related?

I tried to see if there was a Civil Guard office in Corcoya still but I could not find one. Only the one in Herrera so far.

---

#### Translation

Translation based on provided answer:

> On the 11th of August of the marginal year, he joined the Corcoya post
> to render the service of his class, to which he was assigned by order
> of the 1st Chief of the Command where he finished the year.
>
> The 2nd Chief

---

### Related Questions

- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1912 (note 1 of 2)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39451/28260)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestions

> El dia 11 de Agosto año marginal, se **incorporó** al **puesto** de Corcoya
> para **prestar** el servicio de **su** clase, al que fue destinado por orden
> del Señor primer (1º) Jefe de la Comandancia donde finió el año.
>
> El 2º Jefe

Comment: Thanks for the suggested wording changes. I have updated the question with the translation. I can only assume that it was in the best interests that he move from Herrera to Corcoya given the previous problems with the Mayor.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I was just writing you that. Probably the mayor used his influences to have him transferred. In any case, as you said, it was in the best interests of everyone involved.