# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1914 (note 1 of 5)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1914 in my great-grandfathers Civil Guard records there are five entries.

Here is the first one:

[image]

Here is the transcribed text so far:

> Según común que se xxx a la presente fecha 10 de Junio, xxx xxx de le
> Andalucía Territorial de Sevilla, a parece fue osfreseida provisiona
> buento por xxx fecha 19 de Junio, la causa intruida caucha este
> individuo en el Juzgado de Estepa, por detención arbitraria y otro
> hedería que se xxx reipousabriliodad de xxx clase al mismo.
>
> El Comandante Mayor

I know, I have come up with some odd words there! And I am wondering if this is related to the previous note from [1913](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39451/28260) where the **Juzgado de Estepa** was first mentioned.

---

#### Translation

This is the translation based on the supplied answer:

> According to the communication attached hereto dated 10th June, issued
> by the Territorial Court of Seville, the case against this individual
> in the Court of Estepa for arbitrary detention and other facts was
> provisionally dismissed by order dated 19th June, without any
> responsibility of any kind being demanded of him.
>
> The Major Commander

---

### Related Questions

- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1914 (note 2 of 5)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39469/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1914 (note 3 of 5)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39472/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1914 (note 4 of 5)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39474/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1914 (note 5 of 5)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39476/28260)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestions:

> Según **comunicación** que se **une** a la presente fecha 10 de junio, **emanada**
> de la **Audiencia** Territorial de Sevilla, **aparece** fue **sobreseída**
> **provisionalmente por auto** fecha 19 de junio, la causa instruida **contra**
> este individuo en el Juzgado de Estepa, por detención arbitraria y
> otros **hechos** **sin que se exija responsabilidad de ninguna** clase al
> mismo.
>
> El Comandante Mayor.

So, it seems the cause was provisionally dismissed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have updated my question with the initial translation which I think is quite clear and in line with what you said.