# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1914 (note 3 of 5)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1914 in my great-grandfathers Civil Guard records there are five entries.

Here is the second note (it spans two pages):
[image]

[image]

I am assuming that we might be hitting entries pertaining to the first world war as I see his soldier number again. But in all honesty I have found this note to be too hard to read. I can only make out a small number of words. As I result I have not attempted to display an initial transcription because there would be many XXX words.

---

#### Translation

Translation so far:

> Fulfilling this indº (individual) his commitment nº 19.647 at the end
> of August marginal year, he requested and was granted by the 1st Chief
> of his Command a new reenlistment for four years with option to the
> benefits granted by the current Regulations but without prejudice to
> what the Intervention General resolves to terminate (?) the same on 1
> September of this year and will terminate it at the end of August
> 1918, during which time he will enjoy the daily bonus of 25 centimes
> of peseta, and in proof of his agreement he signs this note before the
> undersigned Chief and witnesses.

---

#### Update 1

Updated the translation to take into account the suggested word mentioned in the comments to the answer.

#### Update 2

I split the translation into two parts when using DeepL and have updated the translation. I think it still needs improving though.

---

### Related Questions

- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1914 (note 1 of 5)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39467/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1914 (note 2 of 5)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39469/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1914 (note 4 of 5)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39474/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1914 (note 5 of 5)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39476/28260)

Comment: I think that you have pasted some parts twice in the translation.

Comment: @RubioRic DeepL seems to mess the output sometimes. It is really just one long sentence? I see no full stops or anything.

Comment: I can see no full stops in the original but the final one (that I missed)

Comment: @RubioRic I tried to redo the translation. See what you think.

Comment: I've included my redo in my answer as well. Just removing the extra parts. Remember what we talk about "beginning to extinguish" = "starting" in Spanish.

Comment: @RubioRic Thanks. The only other tweak I have done my end is change the number to **19647** because we would not have the period there.

Comment: "the Intervention General resolves to terminate (?) the same" should be "may resolve definitively, beginning to extinguish (starting) the same"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestions

> Cumpliendo este indº (individuo) su compromiso nº 19.647 en fin de
> Agosto año marginal, solicitó y le fue concedido por el Sr. 1er
> (primer) Jefe de su Comandª (Comandancia) nuevo reenganche por cuatro
> años con opción a los beneficios que concede el vigente Reglamento
> pero sin perjuicio de lo que la Intervención Gral (General) resuelva
> en definitiva dando principio a extinguir (?) el mismo en 1º de Septiembre de
> este año lo terminará en fin de Agosto de 1918 y durante él disfrutará
> el XXX de 25 céntimos de peseta, y en prueba de su conformidad firma
> la presente nota ante el Jefe y testigos que suscriben.
>
> Firmas.

A new reenlisment for 4 years.

I can't figure out the missing word. It doesn't seem to match sueldo/salario/estipendio or any similar word expected as salary.

Note aside: Spain didn't fight in any World War. At that time we were at war with Morocco inhabitans trying to colonize them, maybe we'll see your great grandfather at Alhucemas in a few years.

---

Translation provided by DeepL with minor changes

> Fulfilling this individual his commitment nº 19.647 at the end
> of August marginal year, he requested and was granted by Mr. 1st
> Chief of his Command his reenlistment for four years with option to the
> benefits granted by the current Regulations but without prejudice to
> what the General Intervention may resolve definitively,
> beginning to extinguish (starting) the same on 1st September this year he
> will finish it at the end of August 1918 and during it he will enjoy
> the daily bonus of 25 cents of peseta, and in proof of his agreement he signs this note before the Chief and the undersigned witnesses.

Comment: Seeing how the "p" in "peseta" or "presente" is written, and the final "s" in "céntimos" or "testigos", I would interpret the missing part as "disfrutará el **plus diario** de 25 céntimos de peseta".

Comment: @wimi It makes absolute sense to me. It's a daily bonus.

Comment: @wimi Great catch! I agree with you. It seemed too low as salary.

Comment: Thanks for the translation. I had no idea what it said. Getting into deep waters! :) I have updated the question with the automatic translation, which takes into account the suggested wording by @wimi. Thank you all. So it looks like this was one note and not two.

Comment: Also, thanks for the clarification about WW1. I obviously did not pay attention in History lessons at school!