# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1914 (note 4 of 5)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1914 in my great-grandfathers Civil Guard records there are five entries.

Here is the fourth note:
[image]
This is the transcribed text I have so far:

> 1914: Con el no 44.130 le ha sido admitido por la Ordinen xxx el
> Compromiso que contrajo, a acreditándole en el estado del 3º xxx 125
> pesetas de cuela de entra xxx y 350 pesetas por la final del anterior.
>
> El Comandante Mayor

---

#### Translation

This is the translation so far:

> With the number 44130 has been admitted by the Military Administration
> for the commitment he made, crediting him in the 3rd quarter statement
> with 125 pesetas for the entry fee and 350 pesetas for the end of the
> previous quarter.
>
> The Major Commander

I am not sure where this number **44130** has come from as it differs to the previous solidier number **19647** in the notes. Any ideas?

---

### Related Questions

- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1914 (note 1 of 5)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39467/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1914 (note 2 of 5)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39469/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1914 (note 3 of 5)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39472/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1914 (note 5 of 5)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39476/28260)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess:

> Con el no 44.130 le ha sido admitido por la **Admon. Mtar.
> (Administración Militar)** el compromiso que contrajo,
> **acreditándole** en el estado del 3er **trimestre** 125 pesetas de **cuota de entrada** y 350 pesetas por la final del anterior.
>
> El Comandante Mayor

Comment: Thanks for your translation. I have updated my question with an instal translation based on your answer.