# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1914 (note 5 of 5)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1914 in my great-grandfathers Civil Guard records there are five entries.

Here is the fifth note:

[image]

This is the transcribed text so far:

> En el puesto de la Roda finió el año.
>
> El Comandante Mayor

I think I have read it Ok as it looks similar to other notes.

---

#### Translation

> The year ended at the Roda post.
>
> The Major Commander

Any improvements on that?

---

#### Observations

I find it interesting that this is the first time a note mentions **Roda**. I say this for two reasons:

1. That last note that mentioned him transferring to another site was when it referred to CorCoya. And now he is suddenly in Roda. Do you think this happened when he started his 4 year term?
2. As previously mentioned, my late grandfather was born in 1913 and after some months I tracked down his birth certificate:

[image]

The location where my great-grandfather was working in during 1914 was the same location as where my grandfathers' birth was registered in 1913.

It took some time to eventually locate the right place was [La Roda de Andalucía](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Roda_de_Andaluc%C3%ADa).

Since my grandfather was also registered there in 1913 I wondered if my great-grandfather had transfered sometime earlier.

---

#### Update

I found a link to the [Pesto de La Roda De Andalucia](https://www.guardiacivil.es/es/institucional/directorio/sevilla/puesto_de_la_roda_de_andalucia.html).

---

### Related Questions

- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1914 (note 1 of 5)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39467/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1914 (note 2 of 5)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39469/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1914 (note 3 of 5)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39472/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1914 (note 4 of 5)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39474/28260)

Comment: The subject of the sentence, omitted in Spanish, is "he". The text should read: "At the post of La Roda he finished the year".  It's the same that "He finished the year at the post of La Roda" but written in an archaic manner.

Comment: @RubioRic where would the missing "he" fit in the original Spanish, so I can insert it in `[...]`?

Comment: En el puesto de La Roda (él/ este individuo) finió el año